# r searchTwitter, n maximum number of tweets

Tags: r, twitter

I am trying to capture the maximum number available tweets from a hashtag using the twitterR package using the following commands.

```
searchString<- "dublinbikes -rt -http"
tweets_listDB <- searchTwitter(searchString, n=100)
```

I will be running this each week for the next few weeks to try and capture as much data as a i can. Unfortuately there is not much twitter activity for dublinbikes for the last 7 days and as a result i get the error

> '100 tweets were requested but the API can only return 21'

Is there any way to get the SearchTwitter command to get the maximum number avaliable? So say there are 21 Tweets for the last 7 days, that i return 21 Tweets, if there are 28 Tweets next week, the command returns 28.

Comment: No, there is no way using the search api. See https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/search